# SQL Table with 15m rows performance

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a multi-tier web app for managing patients' folders. Each folder has a number of modules. What I want to do is to keep track of the changes on every module, for every patient, for each user.

So I'm about to design a db table for this, and i estimate that it will escalate up to 15 million rows. The table it will consist of a primary key (int) which it'll be the id, three foreign keys with the id's of the modules, patients' folders, and users (all int), and one simple field with 0/1 values.

Then the logged in user, while navigating in the app, will be frequently informed about any updates with some color code on the folders and the modules. So I will be querying (with simple select queries) the db frequently and i want to be pretty fast in order to keep the user experience to a standard (response time~1sec and lower).

Do i need to have any concerns about the performance? Im using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on a quad core XEON with 4gb RAM.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I think it's more a question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: 4GB RAM is probably too low for SQL Server 2008 R2 with so high loading

Comment: All depends on you "simple select queries": how simple they are and how much data they will return. Try to minimize data-transition. The other crusial question is how many users will you have. Single request is no problem to execute in 1s, but I suppose you'll have hundreds of requests per second and every should be fast - it's completely other question

Comment: I' m more concerned about the performance of the table with the 15m rows. If it takes several seconds to complete each query it will be unacceptable, so there's little difference between lets say 10 or 20secs. The real question is: it will be 1-2 seconds or 10-20 for each query?

Comment: Lets name the 0/1 value "has_changed". The queries will be like e.g. SELECT has_changed WHERE fk_user_id= 1 AND fk_mod_id=1 AND fk_folder_id='1'. Does this query scan the whole table? I think the network cost is minimal considering the amnount of date returned and the fact that for the first few months is LAN only. Also the simultaneous logged-in users will be about 20-30 max.

Comment: Such queries (if they return few rows, less than 100 or so) are almost instantaneous, if you only have created correct indices.

Comment: Most of the time it will be one to 20 rows max returned.

Comment: "will be frequently informed about any updates with some color code on the folders and the modules". If there are 5 updates to single module how do you show this? Do you only represent the _latest_ update? This is an important question which you need to explain further - what exactly are you trying to select and display? If it's only very recent changes then you're better off saving this information immediately into your tables. Please edit your question and clarify. You will definitely need more RAM. You can't even buy a laptop with 4G anymore and databases benefit from RAM - lots!

Comment: To put it another way, what use is an audit record from 2 years ago? will it ever need to be represented? If not, will it be used in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

The scan of 15M row table usually don't take more than a second anyway. So if your question is about single independent request, I think you will not have problems in such conditions.

But for future needs and better performance you might consider adding **non-clustered indexes on the columns "fk_user_id", "fk_mod_id", "fk_folder_id"**. I suppose it will significantly increase the select statement performance (in the cost of decreasing performance of updates).